# WPF TreeViewItem deselected item still lightly highlighted

Tags: wpf, treeview, treeviewitem

I have multiple expander controls with a ViewTree control within each expander control. When I select a ViewTreeItem from one ViewTree and then select another ViewTreeItem from another ViewTree, the newly selected ViewTreeItem is highlighted in dark blue, but the last selected item is now highlighted in a very light shade of blue. Please look at  www.zunjaa.com/public/images/screen.jpg to see what I'm talking about. How do I make it so that no longer active item does not show the lighter blue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by a Trigger in the default template for TreeViewItem:

```
<MultiTrigger>
    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
        <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
</MultiTrigger>
```

Removing this from the default Aero theme template leaves:

```
<PathGeometry x:Key="TreeArrow" Figures="M0,0 L0,6 L6,0 z"/>
<Style x:Key="ExpandCollapseToggleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border Width="16" Height="16" Background="Transparent" Padding="5,5,5,5">
                    <Path x:Name="ExpandPath" Fill="Transparent" Stroke="#FF989898" Data="{StaticResource TreeArrow}">
                        <Path.RenderTransform>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="135" CenterX="3" CenterY="3"/>
                        </Path.RenderTransform>
                    </Path>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="#FF1BBBFA"/>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="Transparent"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="RenderTransform" TargetName="ExpandPath">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="180" CenterX="3" CenterY="3"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="#FF595959"/>
                        <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="ExpandPath" Value="#FF262626"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="19" Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}" ClickMode="Press" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
        <Border x:Name="Bd" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Grid.Column="1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" ContentSource="Header"/>
        </Border>
        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ItemsHost" Value="Collapsed"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Expander" Value="Hidden"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Hi John,

Thank you for your response. I'm not too familiar with WPF. Can you tell me where I can find the default template so I can edit it?

Comment: The quickest way to copy the current template for anything is usually to right click and Edit Template->Edit a Copy in Blend.
To use the above for all TreeViewItems in a Window add the above code into Window.Resources followed by:
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
<Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource MyTemplate}"/>
</Style>

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the help. This is what I ended up with and it works for me:

```
<Window.Resources>
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
  <Style.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
  </Style.Resources>
  <Style.Triggers>
    <MultiTrigger>
      <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
        <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
      </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
    </MultiTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
</Window.Resources>
```